# Serializing a dataTable using protobuf

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

C#, How can I use ProtoBuf .NET to serialize a dataTable?
Can I please have an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about an entire blog entry?

http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/10/datatable-life-in-old-beast.html

Notes:

- this requires v2 (available in the trunk, but still a work-in-progress)
- this requires an additional utility dll (again, in the trunk)

All the code to show how to get this working is in the project in the trunk.

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/DataTableSerializer

Comment: @Gilad - the inbuilt serialization **when set to binary mode** isn't too terrible

Comment: inbuilt serialization? Inbuilt in .Net or inbuilt in protobuf.net?

Comment: Can you please, if you have time, find me a tutorial or a link? I didn't know about the binary mode...

Comment: In my tests I compared to BF after setting the remoting-format

Comment: @Gilad - see Program.cs in the second link

Comment: Oh.. It is part of protobuf.. Thank you, but I don't want to use something thats in progress

Comment: @Gilad - you misunderstand me; that Program.cs shows comparisons between the inbuilt DataTable binary, and protobuf-net; hence it has all the example code you should need for using the inbuilt binary remoting format.

Comment: BTW: I have Serialized List<object> that contains 300 items. I serialized it using protobuf. It weights 2KB. I also have a datatable containing 33 rows that has been serialized using .net binary serializtion and it weights 32KB.

Comment: @Gilad - well it depends in part on how fat each row is; but yes, protobuf is pretty densely packed. I can't take credit for that though. Make sure you set the remoting-format property, note. Otherwise it is just the XML format in a binary package.

Comment: @Gilad `table.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;`

Comment: @Marc - I'm trying to use your protobuf-net to work with DataTables too (using v2 Beta r431 with .NET 2.0 dll). I cannot seem to find the utility dll you mention in your post. Right now I get a "No serializer defined for type: System.Data.DataTable" error. I think I'm missing that dll?

Comment: @mraviator that is not part of the core library, but exists as a standalone project ("ExperimentalDataTableSerializer" or something like that) in the source tree.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/rdingwall/protobuf-net-data

I have released Marc's original code as a library on NuGet, extended with a few more features added.

Comment: This is fantastic, I've been looking for something to compress data before adding to an MS AppFabric cache.  I initially used DefalteStream which created a smaller sized object that protobuf however it took some time (about 6 seconds for 100k records) to get and put to the cache. Using protobuf it takes less than .5 of a second.