# Need to serialize/deserialize dataset using protobuf.net in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net, typebuilder

I am using code like this to define protobuf-net schema at runtime. And i am getting error in:

```
CustomAttributeBuilder contractMem = new CustomAttributeBuilder(
    contractMemInfoCon, new object[] { index });
```

as "Value cannot be null". Please help me to resolve this.

```
AssemblyName oAssemblyName = new AssemblyName();
oAssemblyName.Name = "TEST";
AssemblyBuilder oAssmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly("Test", AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder oModule = oAssmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("TestModule.Module");


TypeBuilder oTypeBuilder = oModule.DefineType("TestType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Serializable);

ConstructorBuilder constructor = oTypeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

//For Defining protocontract                   
ConstructorInfo contractInfoCon = typeof(ProtoBuf.ProtoContractAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);

CustomAttributeBuilder cab = new CustomAttributeBuilder(contractInfoCon,  new object[0]);

oTypeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(cab);
string sDataType = "", sPropertyName = "";
int index = 0;
//oFields contains SP columns
foreach (Types.Field oField in oFields)
{
    sPropertyName = oField.ID;
    sDataType = oField.DataType;
    index = index + 1;

    FieldBuilder field = oTypeBuilder.DefineField(sPropertyName, oField.DataType, FieldAttributes.Public);

    PropertyBuilder property =
    oTypeBuilder.DefineProperty("_" + sPropertyName,
             System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.None,
             oField.DataType,
             new Type[] { oField.DataType });

    MethodAttributes GetSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public |     MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

    MethodBuilder currGetPropMthdBldr =
    oTypeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_value",
                   GetSetAttr,
                   oField.DataType,
                   Type.EmptyTypes);

    ILGenerator currGetIL = currGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
    currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
    currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    MethodBuilder currSetPropMthdBldr =
    oTypeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_value",
                   GetSetAttr,
                   null,
                   new Type[] { oField.DataType });

    ILGenerator currSetIL = currSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
    currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
    currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    property.SetGetMethod(currGetPropMthdBldr);
    property.SetSetMethod(currSetPropMthdBldr);

    ConstructorInfo contractMemInfoCon = typeof(ProtoBuf.ProtoMemberAttribute).GetConstructor(new [] { oField.DataType });
    CustomAttributeBuilder contractMem = new CustomAttributeBuilder(contractMemInfoCon, new object[] { index });
    property.SetCustomAttribute(contractMem);
}
```

Comment: Please try to [edit] your question to add some specifics to your question.  As it is we can't tell what exactly you have tried so far, and what isn't working.  In fact a [mcve] constructing a sample `DataSet` would be ideal.  As it is now, this question is unlikely to get answered.  See [ask] and also https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for how to ask a question more likely to get answered.    All that being said, you could start with [Serializing a dataTable using protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4358098).

Comment: Also, try to tag future questions more fully.  Are you using [tag:protobuf-net]?  Or [Google.Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/csharp)?  Or something else?

Comment: Hi; protobuf-net author here; can I ask: why are you using TypeBuilder here? what is it that you are trying to achieve with meta-programming? Most things in protobuf-net can be *configured at runtime* via the `RuntimeTypeModel` API - I strongly suspect that the IL stuff here is a distraction from what you are actually trying to do. So: what is the thing that you are *actually trying to do*?

Comment: Datasets are evil...only use for simple stuff and definitely not anything distributed..

Comment: Did you find to solve it? I have the same need of sending a Dataset back and forth to gRPC service.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, the *problem* comes from here:

```
ConstructorInfo contractMemInfoCon = typeof(ProtoBuf.ProtoMemberAttribute).GetConstructor(
    new [] { oField.DataType });
```

This will only work when `oField.DataType` is `int`, since the only single-parameter `ProtoContractAttribute` constructor is the one that takes `int tag`. For any other `oField.DataType`, this `GetConstructor` call will return `null`. An immediate fix would be to use `typeof(int)` each time there, rather than `oField.DataType`.

However, frankly I don't think that meta-programming is the right approach for you to use in this scenario (although it is hard to say without a complete example). If you *already have* an object model, many things can be configured using the `RuntimeTypeModel` / `MetaType` / `ValueMember` APIs. I don't know how well that would apply to your specific scenario.

If you are specifically looking at serializing a `DataSet`, then the "right" approach might depend on whether it is a "typed" data-set, vs a non-typed data-set. Frankly, the *first* thing I would say is:

> stop using data-sets

but I acknowledge that there are *some* (limited) scenarios where they are genuinely useful. They shouldn't be your default data access technology. If you *have* to use data-sets (`DataSet`), note that there *already is* an optimized serialization format *built in* - it just isn't enabled by default. If you have tested `DataSet` using inbuilt .NET serialization and found it unsatisfying, try setting:

```
yourDataSet.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
```

and re-run your test. This is *much* more efficient than the default xml format, and might be enough to avoid having to convince `DataSet` to play-nicely with an additional serializer.

Comment: Thanks marc , But in my case, initially i use binary formatter to serialize/deserialize dataset, For increasing the performance (eg: 10 Lakhs records out from DB) i switch over to protobuf.net in which i serialize dataset by using `ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, oDataSet);` it is working fine. How can I deserialize the same. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: @Mathy BinaryFormatter *uses* the RemotingFormat setting; you should at least factor that in and test it with the second inbuilt format. Re protobuf-net and dataset, I very much doubt "it is working fine". If it isn't currently deserializing, how can you possibly say that?

Comment: @Mathy it is very hard to comment more without a specific runnable example. I think your emit approach is a mile wide and doing the wrong thing from the outset, but even that doesn't let me run anything to see what you're seeing.

Comment: Agree with Mark worst projects which were slow with huge complex issues post production roll out used Distributed Datasets.. Proto  ( or any non Xml) + Datasets is a bad idea due to the internal structure of datatables.

Comment: @Mathy can you share your code please. I need to migrate a WCF to gRPC and all the services are using c# Datasets and no way to change that to a Model becuase is a legacy system. Thanks

Comment: @VAAA you have a few options here, and one of them doesn't involve protobuf-net at all! One option might be things like https://github.com/dotarj/protobuf-net-data (which I have never used, so this is not a recommendation, just a "this exists"). However, protobuf-net.Grpc allows you to swap out the marshaller (serializer) for any types, so you could add your own marshaller for DataTable that uses the inbuilt DataTable XML write logic. No idea how well it would work in this case, but: it is an option (I'm the author of both protobuf-net and protobuf-net.Grpc)