# How to Convert DataTable to Protobuf format

Tags: c#, datatable, protobuf-net

How do I convert a `DataTable` to protobuf, in a similar way to how we convert `DataTable` to Json. This is sample code to convert to JSON for example. Is there anyway to do the same with a `DataTable` to protobuf?

```
using Newtonsoft.JSON; 
public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataTable table) 
{ 
    string JSONString=string.Empty; 
    JSONString = JSONConvert.SerializeObject(table); 
    return JSONString; 
 }
```

Comment: Like there is a sample code to convert datatable to json. Is there any to convert datatable to protobuf. using Newtonsoft.JSON;  

public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataTable table)
 {  
   string JSONString=string.Empty;  
   JSONString = JSONConvert.SerializeObject(table);  
   return JSONString;  
}

Comment: [Add that to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56836129/edit).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing a dataTable using protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358098/serializing-a-datatable-using-protobuf)